# Java Gradle Error : Your build is currently configured to use Java 17.0.2 and Gradle 7.3.1

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, build.gradle, java-17

We are attempting to upgrade our project to use Java 17 with a compatible Gradle.  We expect that Java 17.0.2 and Gradle 7.3.1 should be compatible per [Gradle Compatibility Matrix](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html)

However, when we attempt to run our project we get the following error :

```
Unsupported Java. 
Your build is currently configured to use Java 17.0.2 and Gradle 7.3.1.

Possible solution:
 - Use Java 16 as Gradle JVM: Open Gradle settings 
 - Open Gradle wrapper settings, change `distributionUrl` property to use compatible Gradle version and reload the project
```

We are using IntelliJ with Gradle JVM set to : `openjdk-17 version 17.0.2` and Project SDK set to : `openjdk-17 version 17.0.2`

We are using Gradle distribution url : `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.1-all.zip`

It appears that these should be compatible does anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: Try with `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5.1-bin.zip`. If it doesn't work, try a lower minor version e.g. `gradle-7.2-all.zip` or choose another from https://services.gradle.org/distributions/

Comment: What happens if you try on the command line, without IntelliJ? What does `./gradlew assemble`, `java --version`, and `echo $JAVA_HOME` output?

Comment: My project works with Gradle 7.3.1 and JDK 17 on 2022.3 IDE version. Can you provide the sample project? What IDE version do you use? Also please clarify how does it work from the command line with the same JDK and Gradle versions.